# How to make a property with a if-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, properties

my question is, if it's possible, to do something like this:

```
public Class Test
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
  private string text;

  public string Text
  {
    if (Number > 5)
    {
      set {text = value;}
      get {return text;}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, but please explain what you want to do when Number is less or equal to 5?

Comment: Alternatively, describe what problem you try to solve here.

Comment: I want, that it's only possible, to have acess to the attribute text, if the value of Number ist higher then 5.

Comment: You can declare a backing field for your property and then write code in the get/set accessors to raise an exception if the condition is not met.

Comment: Given your explanation in the answer: how about inheritance? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is very much an XY question. Asking for help on a small detail of a totally wrong design.

Comment: The problem of enheritance is, that I need a new Class, for each type of a plant. But I only want to use 1 Class for all types, because I want to create a list form this class, where all Plants can be saved. (The List looks like that: `Plants = new List<Plant>`)

Comment: "a list form this class, where all Plants can be saved" - Which is one of the features of inheritance: `Plant p = new Daffodil();`

Comment: Yes you are right I hadn't known, that it's possible to create a List with differend Items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you could do something like:

```
public class Test {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        private string _Text;
        public string Text {
            get {
                if(Number > 5) {
                    return _Text;
                } else {
                    //DEFAULT value here. 
                    return null;
                }                
            }
            set {
                if(Number > 5) {
                    _Text = value;
                } else {
                    //DEFAULT Value. 
                    _Text = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would also check out Preprocessor Directives if you are using Visual Studio. These might be more helpful depending on how you are trying to use the code.

Preprocess Directives: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty.aspx

Comment: Ok maybe it's possible, to solve my problem on another way. I try to explain it for you. I have a Class, calls Plant. This class has the attributes: string type, string bark, and double height. If I create a new Object of this Class, the attribute bark shouldn't be available, if the value of the type is Flower. Only the attribute height should be available.

Comment: If that is so then @RuardvanElburg is correct. You need to use inheritance.