# How I can validate input field in Webservice in Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, soap

I'm writing a Web service in Asp.net C#, i need to validate field in web service itself, how i can do that? i have given small example below

```
 public class Pack{
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }  
}

[WebMethod]
public string CreateShip(Pack pk){

  List<Ship> Sh = new List<Ship>();
  sh.weight=pk.Weight;

}
```

Here List coming from third party api, I'm assigning weight to third party weight property but in third party they only accept 50kg, so while assigning i need to check weight in web service how i can do that?

Comment: Potential duplicate with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595148/how-to-make-a-property-with-a-if-statement , this would work if you know the limitations. If you don't know what the maximum value is for a property then the web service needs to send a response letting you know that.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: your answer is correct, but I did in another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your properties like the workaround below:

```
public class Pack {
    private double _weight;
    public double Weight {
        get = >_weight;
        set {
            if (_weight > 50) throw new Exception("Weight is limited up to 50k.");
            _weight = value;
        }
    }
    public double Height {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public string CreateShip(Pack pk) {

    List < Ship > Sh = new List < Ship > ();
    sh.weight = pk.Weight;

}
```