# Enum separation between Model and ViewModel in MVVM scenario

Tags: c#, mvvm, enums, model

I am preparing a ViewModel for a Model to be used with a PropertyGrid View. Previously, I was presenting Model directly to the PropertyGrid, which not only made my model clunky, but does not provide a good code separation and forced me to add view-specific code to a model.

Consider following Model:

```
  public enum JobPosition
  {
    None, JuniorEng, MidEng, SeniorEng,
  };

  public class Employee
  {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public JobPosition Position { get; set; }
  }
```

and a corresponding (simplified) ViewModel:

```
  public class EmployeeViewModel
  {
    public Employee Model;

    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [PropertyOrder( 0 )]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Position")]
    [PropertyOrder( 1 )]
    public JobPosition Position { get; set; }
  }
```

How do I handle enumeration separation between Model and a ViewModel in a case, when I want to add desciption to an enum fields and restrict some of them?

**Solution 1**

Redefine enum in ViewModel. This require additional code, but provide similar way of adding attributes like for a ViewModel properties. Also it is possible to skip certain enumerator fields, if they are forbidden from View:

```
  public enum JobPositionViewModel
  {
    [Description( "Junior Engineer" )]
    JuniorEng = JobPosition.JuniorEng,

    [Description( "Engineer" )]
    MidEng = JobPosition.MidEng,

    [Description( "Senior Engineer" )]
    SeniorEng = JobPosition.SeniorEng,
  }
```

Enums can be casted between JobPosition and JobPositionViewModel in a ViewModel.

**Solution 2**

Use TypeConverter. Example TypeConverter could look like this:

```
  public class JobPositionConverter : TypeConverter
  {
    static Dictionary<JobPosition, String> values = new Dictionary<JobPosition, String>( )
    {
      { JobPosition.JuniorEng, "Junior Engineer" },
      { JobPosition.MidEng, "Engineer" },
      { JobPosition.SeniorEng, "Senior Engineer" },
    };

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported( ITypeDescriptorContext context )
    {
      return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues( ITypeDescriptorContext context )
    {
      return new StandardValuesCollection( values.Keys);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom( ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value )
    {
      return values.FirstOrDefault( x => ((String)x.Value).Equals( (String)value, StringComparison.InvariantCulture ) ).Key;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo( ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType )
    {
      return values[ (JobPosition)value ];
    }
  }

  public class EmployeeViewModel
  {
    public Employee Model;

    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [PropertyOrder( 0 )]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Position")]
    [PropertyOrder( 1 )]
    [TypeConverter( typeof( JobPositionConverter ) )]
    public JobPosition Position { get; set; }
  }
```

**Solution 3**

Create list of strings with possible values and handle conversion directly in a property. I will not be presenting code here as it not only looks cheap, but also require from me to create specified editor for a PropertyGrid and manual binding.

Which one do you propose? Is there any more elegant way of solving my problem?

Comment: You can make  the {get;set;} functions.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595148/how-to-make-a-property-with-a-if-statement

Comment: I am aware of getter and setter functions. Maybe I was not clear about my issue - I'm having a combobox made from possible enum values with their proper description. While storing Position as String will help, it does not solve my issue entirely.

Comment: Enum you can do many things in the get/set 1) ToString() which outputs the name of the enum instead of the number 2) Enum.Parse() which converts the string name to the enum 3) Cast to int